# How do I include libraries when compiling with javac?

Tags: java

I have to start the program by terminal for my homework. The project includes a `.java` file, that uses a external libary. Usually I compiled my java files with just the javac command, but it seems, that this doesn't work here. So I looked up and found this:

---

```
javac -cp "dnsjava-2.1.9.jar" Main.java
```

the .java and .jar files are in the same folder. I run the java file with the command: `java main somename`
If I try to run the program, I get the following error:

```
   Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xbill/DNS/TextParseException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xbill.DNS.TextParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Your wording here is unclear. Are you trying to execute a .jar or a .java file?

Comment: @trvlr i try to execute the .java file

Comment: You need to compile the `.java` file before you execute it. So you need to run `javac` first, and then run `java` to execute the `.class` file after it's been compiled.

Comment: Your classpath in `javac` is malformed. Try `javac -cp ".;dnsjava-2.1.9.jar;" Main.java` and make sure you're running javac in the correct directory.

Comment: @DanielPryden that is what I'm doing.

Comment: @trvlr I'm getting the same error

Comment: You have to specify `-cp` for the `java` command too, otherwise it won't find the classes at runtime

Comment: If you're getting a JNI error, it's also possible that your `dnsjava` JAR file contains a native class which doesn't work on your platform, or it requires a native library to be available which you need to install somehow. I don't know that library so I don't know how it's supposed to be used.

Comment: @quinzo Are you on Linux/OSX? If so, replace the semicolons with colons and try again.

Comment: that other guy is also correct. Include the `-cp ...` argument in both `java` and `javac`.

Comment: @trvlr thank you. Didn't know I have to include the -cp ... argument in the java command